# How to deploy Grails app without context path?

Tags: grails, web-applications, contextpath

Not sure if I'm using the term "context path" correctly here, but currently when I run my Grails (2.3.6) app locally, it comes up at `http://localhost:8080/myapp`. Ultimately, I'd like it to be deployed to an actual app server at `http://myapp.com`.

Is this possible? If not, why? If so, how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In config.groovy, just set:

```
grails.app.context = "/"
```

Also, you should probably update your environments in config.groovy as well:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.serverURL = "http://localhost:8080"
    }
    production {
        grails.serverURL = "http://myapp.com"
    }
}
```